# Adding column(s) from one dataframe to another python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have been searching online and found similar questions but still couldn't find the answer to what I'm looking for. 
I have 2 excel files:

data1

```
ColumnA    columnB    columnC   columnD
  A          B          C          D
  A          B          C          D
  A          B          C          D
```

data2

```
ColumnE    columnF    columnG   
  E          F          G          
  E          F          G          
  E          F          G
```

I want to add the column F from data2 to data1:

```
ColumnA    columnB    columnC   columnD  columnF 
  A          B          C          D       F
  A          B          C          D       F
  A          B          C          D       F
```

I tried

```
data2['columnF'] = data1['columnF']  #doesn't work
```

also tried

```
data1['columnF'] = ''   #adding a columnF to data1
merg_left = pd.merge(left=data1,right=data2, how='left',      
left_on='columnF', right_on='columnF')  
#gave me a weird output file
```

Comment: You need to add more detail. Do they have the same index? if so then `data2['columnF'] = data1['columnF']` would work. Are the same shape? Do they have some common index? `pd.concat` is probably what you want to use but until we know what the indices and shape are we can't tell you exactly how to use it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import io

data = """
ColumnA    columnB    columnC   columnD
  A          B          C          D
  A          B          C          D
  A          B          C          D
    """
data1 = """
ColumnE    columnF    columnG
  E          F          G
  E          F          G
  E          F          G
    """

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delimiter='\s+')
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data1), delimiter='\s+')

df['columnF'] = pd.Series(df1['columnF'])

print(df)
```

Will give you:

```
  ColumnA columnB columnC columnD columnF
0       A       B       C       D       F
1       A       B       C       D       F
2       A       B       C       D       F
```

Comment: thank you! i think i understand your code but the data and data1 are 2 files that i have read in using pd.read_csv and pd.read_excel, instead of the simple tables i put up there (wanted to make everything look clean here), and when i assign io.StringIO(data) and io.StringIO(data1) the error message gave "initial_value must be str or None, not DataFrame"  , do you know how i should fix this? thanks

Comment: The `io.StringIO()` are just a way to create your sample data. You should use `read_csv` and `read_excel` as you have. The main part is `df['columnF'] = pd.Series(df1['columnF'])`

Comment: thanks that worked.  if i want to insert that  'columnF' from df1 to the column after 'columnA' in df, would i do something like `df['columnA'+1] = df['columnF']` ?

Comment: That won't work. You'll need `insert` for that. `df.insert(1,'columnF',df1['columnF'])`

Answer (score 16):

```
import pandas as pd
f_column = data2["columnF"]
data1 = pd.concat([data1,f_column], axis = 1)
data1
```

```
     columnA      columnB     columnC     columnF
0       a            b            c         f
1       a            b            c         f
2       a            b            c         f
```