# Loop to merge multiple csv files

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, while-loop, merge

I am new to python. Please advise me following question.

By using *for* or *while* loop, I would like to merge around 200 csv files into a single csv file. Some of csv files with head(5) are like below(Each csv files are 1122 rows * 2 columns).

```
0sec.csv
    ID  Damage
0   0   2697.5
1   2   1431.7
2   3   2719.3
3   4   345.8
4   5   349.1

1sec.csv
    ID  Damage
0   0   507.1
1   2   0.0
2   3   9644.3
3   4   388.7
4   5   0.0
```

My goal is to make a single csv file like below.

```
total_damage.csv
    ID      0sec        1sec    ~~~    199sec        200sec
0   0       2697.5      507.1          xxx.x         xxx.x
1   2       1431.7      0.0            xxx.x         xxx.x
2   3       2719.3      9644.3         xxx.x         xxx.x
3   4       345.8       388.7          xxx.x         xxx.x
4   5       349.1       0.0            xxx.x         xxx.x
```

What I've tried

```
files = sorted(glob.glob('./python/*'))

df = pd.DataFrame()
for i, f in enumerate(files):
    file = pd.read_csv(f)
    file.rename(columns = {'Damage': '{}sec'.format(i)})
    df = pd.merge(df, file)

df.to_csv('./python/total_Damage.csv', index=False)
```

Error message

```
No common columns to perform merge on. Merge options: left_on=None, right_on=None, left_index=False, right_index=False
```

​I would appreciate it if you could teach me current use of pd.merge with loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding column(s) from one dataframe to another python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33532216/adding-columns-from-one-dataframe-to-another-python-pandas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there. First of all, you are not actually renaming because you missed `file=` in front of the rename.

Then, to add a column to a dataframe, you simply do `df[col]=file[col]`.

Therefore:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for i, f in enumerate(files):
    file = pd.read_csv(f)
    file = file.rename(columns = {'Damage': '{}sec'.format(i)})
    df['{}sec'.format(i)] = file['{}sec'.format(i)]
```

Don't forget to add the id column once before iterating.

Comment: Thank you very much. I could solve my problem because of  your help.